# how to convert 3D obj file to particles in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to play around with particles in three.js but, there's a problem with converting obj file (3D model) into particles in three.js. The following is the code snippets. I tried but, all failed.

Is there anyone who can help correcting the errors or provide with any examples of getting vertices/particles from a 3D model in obj?

Thanks a lot.

```
var p_geom = new THREE.Geometry();
var p_material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xFFFFFF,
      size: 1.5
   });

var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

loader.load( 'human.obj',function(object){

      object.traverse( function(child){

         if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

            // child.material.map = texture;

            var scale = 10.0;

            object.attributes.position.array.forEach(function() {
               p_geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(this.x * scale, this.y * scale, this.z * scale));
         
            })
         }
      });
     scene.add(p)

   });

   p = new THREE.ParticleSystem(
      p_geom,
      p_material
   );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an outdated code reference. With recent `three.js` version, the code looks more like the following:

```js
const loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

loader.load('human.obj', function(object) {

  const vertices = [];

  object.traverse(function(child) {
    if (child.isMesh) {
      vertices.push(...child.geometry.attributes.position.array);
    }
  });

  const p_geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  const p_material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    color: 0xFFFFFF,
    size: 1.5
  });

  p_geom.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));

  const p = new THREE.Points(p_geom, p_material);
  p.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
  scene.add(p)

});
```

Comment: You're awesome! Yes, it's from a pretty old project on CodePen (https://codepen.io/robbue/pen/LjshK). I just applied your code to the project and console log showed the error that Type Error: undefined not a constructor ("evaluating new PointsMaterial).  Why?  Isn't it a common function in Three.JS?  I want to get all particles from 3D Obj file and then use WebGL shaders to manipulate the particle vertices. Could you please kindly advise how to adjust the source code?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please make sure that you use the latest version of `three.js`? `PointsMaterial` was introduced at a later point of the engine's lifecycle so maybe it is not defined in your current version.

Comment: You're right. The library used is too old. Can I do this way? I just posted my practice project onto CodePen (https://codepen.io/patrick-sloan/pen/zYdMMbN). Can you help me check what's the problem with the code?  It seems not able to get OBJLoader library. I tried playing around with it for three days and there's no progress.

Comment: I had to remove some of your code since I did not understand of all statements. Maybe you can start from there: https://jsfiddle.net/ntoxme5L/1/

Comment: Hi Mugen87, Thanks a lot. No problem now.